# SELECT CASE withsubquery returs more than one line

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

When I execute the code for partition_date = 2019-12-11 and for partition_date = 2019-07-06 I get an error saying '**The subquery returs more then one line**'. For Other cases it works

```
select case when my_count <=1 AND status_  = 'END' then 0 
                    when my_count >1 AND status_ IN ('END', 'RUNNING', 'START', 'ERR') THEN 1              
                    ELSE -1
               end  AS W 
        INTO return_val
        from (select 
          (SELECT count(DISTINCT(status)) FROM my_table 
          WHERE my_table.HIVE = 'hive1' 
          AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
          AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
        ) my_count,
          (SELECT DISTINCT(status) AS status_ FROM my_table 
          my_table.HIVE = 'hive1' 
          AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
          AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
        )status_
          FROM dual 
            )x  ;
           RETURN(return_val);
```

my_table is like

```
    STATUS |HIVE |PARTITION_DATE     |
    -------|-----|-------------------
    END    |hive1|2019-12-11 00:00:00|
    START  |hive1|2019-12-12 00:00:00|
    NA     |hive1|2019-12-13 00:00:00|
    END    |hive1|2019-09-12 00:00:00|
    END    |hive1|2019-09-13 00:00:00|
    END    |hive1|2019-09-14 00:00:00|
    ERR    |hive1|2019-08-06 00:00:00|
    ERR    |hive1|2019-07-06 00:00:00|
    START  |hive1|2019-07-07 00:00:00|
    RUNNING|hive1|2019-07-08 00:00:00|
    END    |hive1|2019-07-09 00:00:00|
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few status in statement:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT(status) AS status_ FROM my_table 
          WHERE EL_F_BDP_PROC_REALTIME.HIVE = 'hive1' 
          AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
          AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
        )
```

and returned more one line.

For rigth execute you need return one value example:

```
max((SELECT DISTINCT(status) AS status_ FROM my_table 
              WHERE EL_F_BDP_PROC_REALTIME.HIVE = 'hive1' 
              AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
              AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
            ))
```

Is it executing, but ,purhaps ,logic is wrong

Try it:

```
with tbl as (
select 'START' status,     'hive1' str, to_date('2019-12-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt from dual 
union all
select 'NA' status,     'hive1' str, to_date('2019-12-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual 
union all
select 'END' status,     'hive1' str, to_date('2019-12-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual)
select dt, str, listagg(status, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY str) 
from tbl
GROUP BY dt, str
```

Comment: I think you may be using listagg for return all status in one line

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use group by,

SELECT case when my_count <=1 AND status_  = 'END' then 0 
                    when my_count >1 AND status_ IN ('END', 'RUNNING', 'START', 'ERR') THEN 1
                    ELSE -1
               end  AS W 
        INTO return_val
from (select DISTINCT count(status) as my_count,status as status_ FROM my_table 
          WHERE EL_F_BDP_PROC_REALTIME.HIVE = 'hive1' 
          AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
          AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
group by status)res ;